# Raspberry Pi with boots up with Rainbow screen

Tags: boot-issues

How can I fix a Raspberry Pi with Rainbow screen on boot up? I have good voltage coming in and I believe I've formatted and setup the SD card properly. I have two of these boards that do the same thing; I bought them months ago but I am only getting to them now. I bought them off of Amazon and It's way to late to return or exchange them I've been told.

Comment: What port are you getting video out of?  Analog or HDMI?  Can you post a picture of what the rainbow screen looks like?

Comment: Have you tried a new SD card?

Comment: I'm using HDMI port, I've tried two SD cards on two different PI's

Comment: as @Wilf mentioned, try a new image and check your power source.

Comment: I had a similar problem when I first got a Pi. It was a `NOOBS` issue. I can't remember the "fix" (which was a configuration issue), but will search if you can't find it. There was no problem with `Raspbian`.

Comment: I am having the same problem after moving a pi 2 card to a pi 3 and I think it's because I am overclocking the pi 2, but the pi 3 doesn't like the overclock settings.  I'm going to try disabling overclocking before moving the card back over to the pi 3 when I get back to it later.

Comment: In my case, this was caused by using an image for RPi 1 on a RPi 3... Just in case this might help someone

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Do you mean a screen like this?:

[image: debug screen from elinux pic]

If you using a RPi 3 B+, it may just be out of date firmware (see [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/81938/raspberry-pi-boots-to-rainbow-screen-when-trying-to-load-retropie/82762#82762)) - you need to use newer image with the right firmware such as the [offical Raspbian image](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) - older and derivative images may still need to be updated for now (e.g. OctoPrint [[1]](https://github.com/guysoft/OctoPi/issues/505) [[2]](https://github.com/guysoft/OctoPi/issues/504) [[3]](https://github.com/guysoft/OctoPi/issues/509) )

Various troubleshooting methods can be found [here](http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Coloured_splash_screen):

> With current firmware, a coloured splash screen (actually its just
>   four pixels "blown up" by the GPU to full screen) is displayed after
>   GPU firmware (`start.elf`) is loaded. This should be replaced by linux
>   console a second later. However if the coloured screen remains, it
>   suggests the `kernel.img` file is failing to boot. Try replacing it with
>   a known good one.
>
> Immediately after displaying the splash screen, the PI starts
>   consuming a little more current. If the PI resets at that moment, it
>   is an indication that the power supply isn't able to deliver the full
>   current your PI requires, but dips its output voltage below a minimum
>   when loaded with the full current the PI needs.
>
> In some cases (Stuck on the Rainbow Screen), freezing at this point
>   has been fixed by adding `boot_delay=1` to the `config.txt` file. This
>   can be done from a Windows PC, which should show several files in the
>   FAT partition on your SD card including `bootcode.bin`, `kernel.img`, and
>   `config.txt`. You can open `config.txt` in wordpad or any text editor. Add
>   `boot_delay=1` and save the file. Don't forget to 'eject' the card
>   before removing it from the card reader. If you are reading the SD card
>   from a working Pi, you can edit the file with `sudo nano
>   /boot/config.txt`
>
> ## Kernel Panic on boot
>
> Text appears on screen, but then hangs with debug messages. This can
>   be caused by USB devices such as keyboards. Try again with nothing in
>   the USB.
>
> ## Raspberry Pi shuts down (or restarts) soon after booting up
>
> This is caused by a power supply producing too low a voltage. See [Troubleshooting power problems](http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Troubleshooting_power_problems)
>
> ## Pi boots sometimes but not always
>
> With a known good power supply and known good SD card, the R-Pi boots
>   occasionally, but other times shows only a tiny green flicker from the
>   "OK" LED and it fails to start, even with no USB devices and no
>   Ethernet. This has been reported several times<sub>[[4] [5] [6]](http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#cite_note-4)</sub> and remains
>   an open issue. Low voltage or an improper SD card can cause it. Some
>   SD cards will work until they warm up slightly, and then fail<sub>[[7]](http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#cite_note-7)</sub>. When exposed to 21 C room temperature the warmest part of an uncased working R-Pi should be 41 C<sub>[[8]](http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#cite_note-8)</sub>. The wiki has a list of working SD
>   cards. Buy from a reliable vendor as it has been claimed that 1/3 of
>   all "Sandisk" labelled memory cards are counterfeit.
>
> - It could be that the SD memory card is not making proper contact with the Raspberry Pi. Look at the SD card holder on the Raspberry Pi
>     carefully. At first glance it may look fine, but the contacts must be
>     springy and they must protrude at least 2mm as measured from the lower
>     edge of the holder to the top of the contact bulge. Variations happen
>     due to the solder process and the type of holder used. Some of the
>     solder residue falls into the contact cavity, restricting the
>     springiness and the height that the contact protrudes. You can fix
>     this yourself, but remember you can void your warranty. The contacts
>     are delicate, so be careful. Insert a needle pin under the contact
>     bulge and pull lightly up until the one end of the contact unclips.
>     Clean the cavity where the contact unclipped from any solder or other
>     residue by blowing into the cavity. Clip the contact back into the
>     cavity by lightly pushing it into the cavity. Do this for all the
>     contacts. Refer to these photos: [Media:SDcardHolder.JPG](http://elinux.org/images/4/46/SDcardHolder.JPG),
>     [Media:UnclipContact.JPG](http://elinux.org/images/5/5a/UnclipContact.JPG), [Media:UnclippedContact.JPG](http://elinux.org/images/8/8f/UnclippedContact.JPG)

I would try other SD cards and power supplies, and check the Pi for defects, as well as different [raspberry pi image](http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/). You may also want to try a different SD card reader, as some may format the card unreliably.

Comment: I also had problems booting my RPi and running fsck on the SD-Card and then booting the RPi with no peripherals did the trick.

Comment: **My Symptom:** "Immediately after displaying the splash screen, the PI starts consuming a little more current. If the PI resets at that moment, it is an indication that the power supply isn't able to deliver the full current your PI requires, but dips its output voltage below a minimum when loaded with the full current the PI needs." **My Problem:** The USB cable was not delivering enough current, the voltage was fine but when I managed to put a meter between the Raspberry pi and the USB cable it was dropping up too 250ma sometimes compared to what the wall adapter to USB cable was delivering

Comment: My Raspberry Pi B+ works perfectly when I plug in an sd card, HDMI cable, and power. When I plug the EXACT SAME wires + card that work for the pi B+ into the pi 2, it freezes at the rainbow screen. Does this mean it's definitely a hardware problem?

Comment: @LukeTaylor - what current is the power supply rated for and how long is the USB cable? (probably too late sry). It may just be a issues that the Pi 2 (and 3) need atleast 800mA of power, whilst the Pi B+ probably needs about 600mA.

Comment: The rainbow screen can also appear if you attempt to boot Raspbian Jessie on a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+. (see [*Raspberry Pi boots to rainbow screen when trying to load RetroPie*](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/82762/84497))

Answer (score 4):

For me, inserting `boot_delay=1` into `config.txt` did not work. Running fsck on the boot partition (/dev/mmcblkop1) uncovered file corruption which couldn't be auto-fixed. I ended up deleting the contents of the boot partition and copying over the contents of `/boot` from my Raspberry Pi Linux tarball. I then had to edit `cmdline.txt` and change `root=/dev/mmcblkop2` to be `root=/dev/mmcblkop5`

Comment: Worked for me using the new raspberry pi 2 B , while having the rainbow screen / coloured screen problem!

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this problem by getting a better power supply. I then took out the microsd card as it booted into recovery mode. I put it back in and was able to install noobs.

Comment: Agreed! Switching from a USB power supply rated 2.1 A to a 750 mA power source (a phone charger) did (curiously!) the trick. The booting process hang when the device tried to switch from the `simple` graphics driver to the VC4 driver, so (perhaps?) a power spike occured during that moment, and the other charger, despite being able to provide greater current, wasn't able to cover it.

Answer (score 0):

I have experinced this on a Model B. I tried various SD cards, but all had the same issue. I then plugged my Samsung Galaxy charger into the Pi, which outputs slightly higher voltage, and it fixed it. Apparently the power supply, supplied with the Pi isnt man enough to do the job it was supposed to do!

Try changing the power supply, before you go too deep into other paths.