# issue with upgrading Debian Jessie (MINIBIAN distro)

Tags: debian, update, minibian

I'm trying to use the MINIBIAN distro as a minimal OS for my raspberry pi 3. Which as far as I know is based on Debian Jessie.
I tried to use

> apt-get upgrade

to upgrade my OS, however after I reboot the system does not boot. What it shows is a weird box with all shades of basic colours in it and it does not respond to any keystroke.

[image]

I would appreciate if you could help me understand what is the problem and how i can solve it.

P.S. I also made this issue at [official MINIBIAN sourceforge repo](https://sourceforge.net/p/minibian/discussion/general/thread/6a9fe900/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Raspberry Pi with boots up with Rainbow screen](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/19354/raspberry-pi-with-boots-up-with-rainbow-screen)

Comment: Minibian is a minimal Raspbian, and uses the standard formware.

Comment: from a very fast review it seems my issue is kind of different. I can boot normally if I do not `apt upgrade` but i will check it again tomorrow. thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt update` before upgrade.

Comment: Yes I did. But I rebooted afterwards and there were no issues