# Raspberry install centos

Tags: raspi-config

Im a new in rapsberry.

I want to install centos but I have never used rapsberry. I used arduino.

I downloaded centos 6 for pi. Sd card is ready. But rasrberry the rainbow stays on the screen. 
[image: My raspberry]

and

[image: Screen]

How can I fixed it?

EDIT:

I changed usb cable and adaptor. But result is same.

Comment: so, you downloaded the centos image, good start ... when you say "the sd card is ready" ... what exactly does that mean? did you "burn" the image onto the sd card, or did you simply copy the downloaded image to the card?

Comment: though ... that looks like a pi1 - where did you get the centos image for pi?

Comment: Yes I burned into sd card. I think Otherwise, it doesn't come rainbow screen. 
@JaromandaX

Comment: And i downloaded in centos web site. The file name: CentOS-Userland-7-armv7hl-RaspberryPI-Minimal-sda.raw.xz @JaromandaX

Comment: Normally this is because you have a bad USB cable or power supply. And its an quite normal question, https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/19354/raspberry-pi-with-boots-up-with-rainbow-screen

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Raspberry Pi with boots up with Rainbow screen](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/19354/raspberry-pi-with-boots-up-with-rainbow-screen)

Comment: `armv7hl` ... and that's an original raspberry pi, or is it a pi2 or pi3?

Comment: I changed usb cable and adaptor. It didn't work again. @MatsK

Comment: original pi (i.e. with only 26 gpio pin header) is an armv6 not armv7 - so, I can't see it working ...

Comment: Please read the duplicate thread for pointers. And in the future, please search first before asking, there is a lot of info posted about this topic. And when I experienced it it was a bad USB cable.

Comment: `I downloaded centos 6` `The file name: CentOS-Userland-7-....` - so, 6 or 7?

Comment: *"Supported armhfp boards

We currently support the following board types :

    RaspberryPI ( model 2, model 3, model 3B+) "* ... see how there's no mention of original pi ... yet you have an original pi ... not a 2, or 3 or 3+ ... it's **not supported** - I've mentioned this incompatibility at least twice already

Comment: I'm going to guess that the `act` light on your pi flashes 7 times - which means `7 flashes: kernel.img not found` - because there is no kernel image compatible with your pi in that centos image because it doesn't support armv6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the image in your question, it is clear that you have an original Pi B

The ARM chip in the Pi B (and A, and B+) is an armv6

There is no Centos image available for the original raspberry pi (armv6), only raspberry pi 2, 3 and 3+ (armv7)

There is a "definitive" list of available operating systems for the raspberry pi [at this link](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/534/definitive-list-of-operating-systems) ... note that under Centos (and others) it clearly states "Pi 2/3 Only"

The **only** solution is to buy a Raspberry Pi 2B, 3B, 3B+ or 3A+ - all of which have the prerequisite armv7 CPU (and are cheaper to buy than the original in my experience)