# OS based on CentOS/Fedora?

Tags: pi-zero

I’m looking for an OS based on CentOS/Fedora to install on a ARMv6.
Anybody know an actual system?

All systems that I found are unmaintained...

Comment: From the fedora architectures page: "The Raspberry Pi 2/3 is now supported in in all stable Fedora releases."  https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Architectures/ARM/Raspberry_Pi

Comment: Yes. Operating System. Are you sure that armv6 is supported on rpi?

Comment: Well, armv6 is compatible with the pi. I'm not sure about the armv6 fedora image. Luckily they seem to have a pi-specific image, though (check the link in my previous comment).

Answer (score 1):

Fedora specifically do not wish to support ARMv6 (and by extension, the Pi Zero). See [their wiki](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Architectures/ARM/Raspberry_Pi#What_about_support_for_the_Raspberry_Pi_Models_A.2FA.2B.2C_B.2FB.2B_.28generation_1.29.2C_Zero.2FZeroW_and_Compute_Module.3F):

> ### What about support for the Raspberry Pi Models A/A+, B/B+ (generation 1), Zero/ZeroW and Compute Module?
>
> THESE ARE NOT SUPPORTED!!!
>
> Fedora doesn't, and NEVER will, support ARMv6 processors. There's been a number of attempts to support these over the years. The current best effort is Pignus based on Fedora 23. More information can be found at [the Pignus site](https://pignus.computer/). Support for the Compute Module 3 (CM3) has landed upstream in the 4.20 kernel and we will support a number of devices based on CM3 in Fedora 30.

Unfortunately Pignus appears to be dead, and their website has vanished from existence, leaving only an [inactive GitHub organisation](https://github.com/pignus-project).

Unless things have changed very recently, the case is the [same for CentOS](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/94255/58316), so it seems you're probably out of luck with the main Red Hat derivatives, sadly.