# Boot ups but display rainbow screen on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: pi-3, boot, raspberry-pi-os, lcd

I'm new in RPi, so can't resolve an problem. How can I fix a Raspberry Pi with Rainbow screen? I'm using Raspberry Pi 3 B with Raspian 10 (show below)

`Linux raspberrypi 5.10.103-v7+ #1529 SMP Tue Mar 8 12:21:37 GMT 2022 armv7l GNU/Linux`

Boot occur correctly, I can connect via ssh normally, but on LCD display rainbow screen.
I'm also using LCD Touchscreen 7inch.

I searched several forums and they talked about power supply and `kernel.img`. But I already checked everything and it didn't fix it.

Some forums that searching:

- [Raspberry Pi with boots up with Rainbow screen](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/19354/raspberry-pi-with-boots-up-with-rainbow-screen)
- [Troubleshooting with the Raspberry Pi](https://www.screenly.io/blog/2018/11/22/raspberry-pi-troubleshooting/)
- [Raspberry Pi 3 B-model showing a rainbow screen on first boot](https://www.reddit.com/r/raspberry_pi/comments/4h0qi4/raspberry_pi_3_bmodel_showing_a_rainbow_screen_on/)

How I can resolve this?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details about the type of display and how it's connected. Add links to the forum posts you followed and add details about the "everything" you already checked. Can you show a photo fo the "rainbow screen"?

Comment: Ok, question edited. Thanks!

Comment: How did you check that the power supply is really supplying 5v0 to the pins of the Rasp Pi?