# boot_delay default value

Tags: pi-4, boot-issues

I had the problem that my Raspberry Pi 4 didn't boot (rainbow screen). After adding a `boot_delay=1` in the `config.txt` the problem was solved. (See [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/19356))

But according to the [docs](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/config_txt.html#boot_delay) the default `boot_delay` is already 1 second, so in my opinion there should be no difference. Can anyone explain me, why setting the value (to the default value) still solved my boot issue?

Comment: if you now remove the line, does the pi again fail to boot

Comment: The linked "answer" is **8 years old** and refers to a different Pi and an obsolete OS.

Comment: @Milliways I know, this is why I was wondering how this could help me out.

Comment: @JaromandaX I'll try this and give you an update. Maybe I was just lucky and it was not the solution.

Comment: @JaromandaX I removed the line and could not reproduce this issue. Any tips what could have solved the problem? It sounds silly, but it seems that only removing the SD card from the PI, mounting and ejecting it on Windows and putting the SD card back again solved the issue...